# How to include folder with resource in Maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a robot resource file within a folder and want to include both the folder and robot resource file when I perform a Maven install.

Here is the project structure:

Project > Folder > robot resource file

Project > src > main > java ...

In my pom.xml file, I've added:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>/Project/Folder</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.robot</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

When I perform Maven install, I only see the robot resource file inside the jar but don't see the Folder for it. How can I make it so that the robot resource file is inside the Folder? I am new to Maven so I'd appreciate any guidance. I've seen this reference but this doesn't provide the answer: http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-resources-plugin-2.6/examples/resource-directory.html

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try :          <directory>Folder</directory>

Comment: Yes, I did and the folder wasn't present in the jar as well.

Comment: Best is to put that into `src/main/resources` including the directory and that's it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Why does it not include the folder?

First, `<directory>` **looks into** the specified folder, but will not include the folder itself. Second, the notation for the project root is not `Project`, but `${project.basedir}`.

#### Proposed solution

Specify a directory that is a level higher than the directory you want to include.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.robot</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: I just tried this and the jar does not include the folder as well. Thanks for the suggestion though.